# GROUP BY, ORDER BY and taking first in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq, oracle10g

Suppose I have a table with two columns:

```
TABLE A
-------
ProjectID           NUMBER
STATUS              VARCHAR2(6) // either 'CLOSED' or 'NEW'
```

There could be maximum two entries for a `ProjectID` with the two possible values of `STATUS` and the combination (`ProjectID`, `STATUS`) is unique.

I need to select only those `ProjectID`'s that have status 'NEW'. Also, if for a `projectID`, there are two entries with different statuses (NEW and CLOSED), I don't want it in the output.

I tried using group by, then ordering the resultset descending (so as to get 'NEW' row for a project ID first) and then taking the first row in LINQ, similar to this:

```
   var query = (from a in context.A.Where(o => o.STATUS == 'NEW')
               group a by a.ProjectID into groups
               select groups.OrderByDescending(o => o.ProjectID)
               .ThenBy(o => o.STATUS)
               .FirstOrDefault());
```

Butt it's resulting into an "APPLY" clouse in the query which is resulting into an error. Apparantly, Oracle 10g doesn't support it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you´ve tried and where you were stuck. In particular add the exact error you got.

Comment: @HimBromBeere See the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Proper tu use `having count(distinct STATUS=1)` :

```
create table tableA( ProjectID int, STATUS varchar2(10) );
insert all
  into tableA values(1    ,'NEW')
  into tableA values(1    ,'CHANGED')
  into tableA values(2    ,'NEW')
  into tableA values(3    ,'CHANGED')
select * from dual; 
/
select * from
(
select ProjectID, max(STATUS) STATUS
  from tableA
 group by ProjectID
having count(distinct STATUS)=1
)
where STATUS = 'NEW';
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test (projectid, status) as
  2    (select 1, 'new'    from dual union     -- should be returned
  3     select 2, 'new'    from dual union
  4     select 2, 'closed' from dual union
  5     select 3, 'closed' from dual union
  6     select 4, 'new'    from dual           -- should be returned
  7    )
  8  select projectid
  9  from test
 10  group by projectid
 11  having min(status) = max(status)
 12     and min(status) = 'new';

 PROJECTID
----------
         1
         4

SQL>
```

Comment: I can write the query but I need to use LINQ.

Comment: Well, such a query returns what you need. Unfortunately, I don't know LINQ, but I hope that you'll be able to apply what you see above to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have accomplished what you want, using a subquery in LINQ.

```
var query = (from a in context.A
                         where (from b in context.A
                                where b.ProjectID == a.ProjectID
                                select new { a.ProjectID, a.STATUS }).Distinct().Count() == 0
                                && a.STATUS == "NEW"
                         select a.ProjectID).ToList();
```

Essentially, the outer query just makes sure that each `a` record has a `NEW` status, and the inner query makes sure that there are no two distinct records with the given ProjectID, because if there are, one is `CLOSED`. I avoided using a `GROUP BY` since you said your database does not support LINQ's way of doing it.

I hope I understood your problem correctly, and I hope this helps!